Two non-isomorphic linear orders with the same covering relation
Let $(L,\leq)$ be a linear order. The covering relation associated with $(L,\leq)$ is the binary relation on $L$ that holds between $x$ and $y$ if and only if $x < y$ but there is no $z$ such that $x<z<y$. I want to know, does there exist a set $L$ and two linear orders $\leq_1$ and $\leq_2$ on $L$ such that both $\leq_1$ and $\leq_2$ have the same covering relation, but $\leq_1$ and $\leq_2$ are not isomorphic? Of course, in such a case, $L$ would have to be an infinite set.

Is there any structure defined between covering pair? Or is the covering relation just the set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \prec y$?

@amrsa The latter.

Then the covering relation is just a set, and up to isomorphism is given by its cardinality. In that case, for example the positive integers and the negative integers, with the usual order, are non-isomorphic and have the same covering relation. Or is there another requirement I'm not seeing?

Take $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0, 1] \cup \mathbb{Q}$?

@amrsa The covering relations have to be the same as sets of ordered pairs, not just isomorphic (this is why the underlying sets need to be the same for this question to make sense).

Picking on @JeanAbouSamra example, one could say $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ as a trivial example, since in both of these, the covering relation is empty. I suspect the OP will object about it :)

@amrsa Again, as the question indicates the underlying sets of the two linear orders have to be the same. (That said, that example can be tweaked to actually work; see my answer.)

Yeah, I was meaning "identified by a bijection" and going to write it but you were quicker :-)

@NoahSchweber Ah, ok, thanks for pointing out. I'll leave the comment for a while.

Any two dense linear orders have empty covering relation. So we can do this as follows:

Find two dense non-isomorphic linear orders $(A,<_A), (B,<_B)$ whose underlying sets have the same cardinality (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual ordering in each case).

Fix a bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$.

Now let $L=B$, $<_1=<_B$, and $<_2=\{(a,b): f^{-1}(a)<_Af^{-1}(b)\}$. The two linear orders $(L, <_1)$ and $(L_, <_2)$ are non-isomorphic but have identical (empty) covering relations.


(If you want to avoid uncountable linear orders in the above approach, use $\mathbb{Q}$ and $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ instead.)

On the other hand, some linear orders cannot serve as one half of an example. For instance, let $L=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $<_1$ be the usual ordering on the integers. If $<_2$ is any other linear ordering on the same set, then (just by virtue of being a linear ordering) $<_2$ contains the transitive closure of its covering relation. But the transitive closure of the covering relation of $<_1$ is $<_1$ itself, so if $<_2$ has the same covering relation as $<_1$ then in fact $<_2=<_1$ (since distinct linear orders on the same set are either equal or $\subseteq$-incomparable as relations). Similarly, $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$ is determined up to isomorphism (but not equality!) by its covering relation: the only freedom we have once we pin down the covering relation is with regard to how we order the "$\mathbb{Z}$-pieces."
On the other hand, as Jean Abou Samra commented below, $1+\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}+1$ (appropriately construed to have the same underlying set) are scattered non-isomorphic linear orders with the same covering relations. So - contra an earlier guess of mine - some scattered countable linear orders can be used as counterexamples too. (It was early, my coffee hadn't kicked in yet!)

Aren't $1 + ℤ$ and $ℤ + 1$ a counterexample to your conjecture?

@JeanAbouSamra Yup, I was being silly!
